# java json string into json array

Tags: java, arrays, json, type-conversion

I have a JsonArray as a string with multiple JsonObjects in it. Since I am not a java developer I am a little bit confused, since it is so complicated to convert JsonObjects into strings and strings into JsonObjects.

I have this [JsonArray](https://pastebin.com/PF3Ps5EB) as a string.

```
[{
    "id":"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
    "name":"Name"
},{
    "id":"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
    "name":"Name"
}]
```

It changes and I don't know what data it includes.

**Goal:** I need to convert the json string into JsonArray so I can work with. I tried gson but I only got empty objects.

**What I tried:**

```
Gson g = new Gson();
JSONObject jsons[] = g.fromJson(JsonString, JSONObject[].class);
```

Output:

```
Log.e ( "JSON", Integer.toString(jsons.length)); ---> 2 (Right!)
Log.e ( "JSON", jsons[0].toString()); ---> { } empty Object
```

Comment: It's not that complicated. `I tried gson but I only got empty objects.`  Post the code that you tried. You are likely doing something easily resolvable.

Comment: Updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `JsonArray` instead of `JsonObject[]`.
Sample code:

```java
String json = "[{ " + 
              "    \"id\":\"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX\", " + 
              "    \"name\":\"Name\" " + 
              "},{ " + 
              "    \"id\":\"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX\", " + 
              "    \"name\":\"Name\" " + 
              "}]";
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonArray array = gson.fromJson(json,JsonArray.class);
System.out.println(array);
```

Output:

```java
[{"id":"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX","name":"Name"},{"id":"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX","name":"Name"}]
```

If you want to work with a `JsonObject[]` you could do something like this:

```java
JsonArray array = gson.fromJson(json,JsonArray.class);
JsonObject[] objects = new JsonObject[array.size()];
for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++)
    objects[i] = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
for(JsonObject x : objects)
    System.out.println(x);
```

Output:

```java
{"id":"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX","name":"Name"}
{"id":"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX","name":"Name"}
```

Comment: I don't need it as a `JsonObject[]`, an JsonArray is fine as well. Your code above works, don't know why I couldn't find it out myself, propably becauseI was working for too long. Thx